# GWT RequestFactory - different views of 1 EntityProxy

Tags: java, requestfactory

I have one DocumentEntityProxy with the following methods :

```
String getAttribute1();
void setAttribute1(String s);
String getAttribute2();
void setAttribute2(String s);
String getAttribute3();
void setAttribute3(String s);
```

What I want to achieve is that if you are a standard user you can only use getAttribute1() and setAttribute1() if you are an admin user you can use all methods. In this example I have only three attributes  and 2 different kind of users but in a real project there are a lot more of course.

What is the best way to achieve that ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could work with inhertance:

```
class UserEntity {
  String getAttribute1() { }
  void setAttribute1(String s) { }
}

class AdminEntity extends UserEntity {
  String getAttribute2() { }
  void setAttribute2(String s) { }
}
```

And the proxies:

```
@ProxyFor(UserEntity.class)
interface UserEntityProxy extends EntityProxy {
  String getAttribute1();
  void setAttribute1(String s);
}

@ProxyFor(AdminEntity.class)
interface AdminEntityProxy extends UserEntityProxy {
  String getAttribute2();
  void setAttribute2(String s);
}
```

To secure access to the entity types you can have two finder methods (returning userEntity or adminEntity) and limit access to the methods in back-end, e.g. with SpringSecurity's @Secured annotation.